# Expected ';' but got 'constructor'

Tags: ethereum, solidity

**Hi everyone, i wrote some solidity code, but unfortunately got some error, what's the matter?**

I was using HardHat to compile my code and got next error:

*Error looks like this:*
ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'constructor'
--> contracts/Tree.sol:14:5

*Code looks like this:*

```solidity
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Tree {
   bytes32[] hashes;
   string[4] transactions = [
       "first transaction",
       "second transaction",
       "third transaction",
       "fourth transaction"
   ];

   constructor() {
       for (uint i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
           hashes.push(makeHash(transactions[i]));
       }

       uint count = transactions.length;
       uint offset = 0;

       while (count > 0) {
           for (uint i = 0; i < count - 1; i += 2) {
               hashes.push(
                   keccak256(
                       abi.encodePacked(
                           hashes[offset + 1],
                           hashes[offset + i + 1]
                       )
                   )
               );
           }
           offset += count;
           count = count / 2;
       }
   }

   function verify(
       string memory transaction,
       uint index,
       bytes32 root,
       bytes32[] memory proof
   ) public pure returns (bool) {
       bytes32 hash = makeHash(transaction);
       for (uint i = 0; i < proof.length; i++) {
           bytes32 element = proof[i];
           if (index % 2 == 0) {
               hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(hash, element));
           } else {
               hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(element, hash));
           }
           index = index / 2;
       }
       return root == hash;
   }

   function encode(string memory input) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
       return abi.encodePacked(input);
   }

   function makeHash(string memory input) public pure returns (bytes32) {
       return keccak256(encode(input));
   }
}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue - the provided code compiles without the error. But it seems like you forgot to semicolon `;` after the end of `transactions` array, however you did put it here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Above provided code is completely Okay and compiles fine.

However, it issue might be that you have missed a semicolon `;` at the end of array string `transactions` while compiling however, replaced here while uploading the code.